# When the Hessian matrix is indefinite, why does the point have to be a saddle point?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, hessian-matrix

Simply a question that occurred to me and proof which I can't seem to find. I realise that if the Hessian matrix is indefinite, it's determinant is less that zero but how does that mean that the point is a saddle point?

Comment: It is not true that indefinite Hessian matrix means that its determinant is negative. Try for example $x^2+y^2-z^2-w^2$, whose Hessian is $\operatorname{Diag}(2,2,-2,-2)$ with determinant $+16$. (Though it is true if you have only two independent variables).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I presume we're talking about a twice differentiable function $f$ defined in a neighbourhood of a point $p = (p_1, p_2, \ldots, p_n)$ such that the gradient $\nabla f(p) = 0$, and the Hessian matrix $H = H(f)(p)$ is indefinite.  Thus there exist eigenvectors $u$ and $v$ of $H$ corresponding to eigenvalues $\lambda$ and $\mu$ which are positive and negative respectively.  From the Taylor expansion
$$ f(p + \epsilon x) = f(p) + \epsilon x^T \nabla f(p) + \frac{\epsilon^2}{2} x^T H x + o(\epsilon^2)$$
we find that $$f(p + \epsilon u) = f(p) + \frac{\epsilon^2 \lambda u^T u}{2} + o(\epsilon^2)$$
and similarly $$f(p + \epsilon v) = f(p) + \frac{\epsilon^2 \mu v^T v}{2} + o(\epsilon^2)$$
so
$f(p + \epsilon v) > f(p) > f(p + \epsilon u)$ for sufficiently small $\epsilon>0$, and thus $p$ is a saddle point.

Answer (score 0):

If a Hessian has both positive and negative eigen values then it is indefinite.The function is neither convex nor concave.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).